# get index from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, arraylist

I am building music player app for that I gathering data from SDcard which downloaded from the server and save files name into **ArrayList**

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Now the problem is I want to play mp3 file according to the user click on recycler item so for that, I want index number for the particular name.

How can I get an **index** for passing name of the mp3 file??

```
/**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                Log.d(TAG, "getPlayList() called title = "+file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4))+"  Path = "+file.getPath());
                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }
```

Comment: I advise you to make a `Song` class instead of storing properties in a HashMap

Comment: yes, POJO would be a good option but I already implemented HashMap so now it will take a time to implement and changes in all classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your construction, you could loop over the list to find the map you need

```
int indexForSongName(String songName) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> playlist = getPlayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < playlist.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = playlist.get(i);
        if (map.containsValue(songName)) { // Or map.getOrDefault("songTitle", "").equals(songName);
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1; // Not found.
}
```

That said, I advise you to make a Song class instead of storing properties in a HashMap. It is good practice and it would make tasks such as these easier.

Comment: i will try your answer and let you know

Comment: Thank you, genius  its work like charm and I will remember your advice in future